# Skewness of random variable and its linear transformation

Tags: random-variables, expectation, moment-generating-functions, means

I'd like to prove that a random variable $X$ and it's linear transformation $Y = aX+b, a>0$ have the same skewness coefficient, where the skewness coefficient is, according to Pearson, given by:

$$\gamma_x = \frac{\kappa_3}{\kappa_2^{1.5}}=\frac{E[(X-E[X])^3]}{\sigma_X^3}$$

Where $\kappa_2 = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}k_x(t)$ at $t=0$ and $\kappa_3 = \frac{d^3}{dt^3}k_x(t)$ at $t=0$ and $\kappa_x(t):= log [m_x(t)]$.

Since the variance of a random variable is equal to $\kappa_2$ I determined that the denominator of the skewness coefficient of $Y$, $\gamma_Y$, is equal to $(a^2\sigma_X^2)^{1.5}=a^3\sigma_X^3$.

The numerator of $\gamma_Y$ is equal to $E[(Y-E[Y])^3] = E[(Y-(aE[X]+b))^3]$, any help with calculating this expectation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $Y = aX + b$, we have
$$ Y - E[Y] = aX + b - aE[X] - b = a(X - E[X]) $$
Hence, the numerator of $\gamma_Y$ is 
$$ E[(Y - E[Y])^3] = a^3 E[(X- E[X])^3]. $$